# Updating game backups without moving the entire folder again

Tags: backup, windows-explorer, file-transfer

I have an External HDD for my game backups, but every time there's an update I have to move the entire game folder again and choose "Replace all files".

Is there a way I can only copy the changed/updated files to the backup drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `robocopy` from the command line with the /XO and /MIR options, it will mirror a directory and skip older files.

For example:

`robocopy /mir /zb /xo /copyall C:\MyGames\GameA B:\Backups\GameA`

See [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for more info.

If copying to/from a network share, add the /FFT option.